# After mounting netapp to directory the inside directory doesn't exist

Tags: linux, mount, cifs, netapp

I am trying to mount our netapp but after mounting im getting weird result.
I will give the weird results. We are trying to mount a netapp DFS share.

First i tried to mount without a specific domain.

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,mand,user=<user>,password=<passowrd>,noserverino //ip/dfs <directory path>
```

The mount worked but i couldn't access the inner directories.
The message:

> bash: cd: : No such file or directory

Then i tried to mount with specific domain.

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,mand,user=<user>,password=<passowrd>,noserverino,domain=<domainName> //ip/dfs <directory path>
```

The mount also worked it but now when i tried to access the directory i got the message: **

> bash: cd: : Permission denied

I also know it should work because i was able to view the share via a windows 7 station and it worked perfectly.
Also, i used the file manager of gnome and used "connect to server". It also worked and i could access the inner directories.

If you need more information let me know, and thank you for the help.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I will ask there and i'm sorry my mistake.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)